# PHP, SQL, and JQuery paging error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm following this tutorial here: http://brenelz.com/blog/implementing-paging-using-php-and-jquery/

Here is what I have: http://eataustineat.com/testingfolder/

I've encountered a strange problem when the page initially loads. All that shows is the Next and previous link when the first set of results and the next link should be present.  Once you click next or previous, then the the results show.  But after that, the next and previous links no longer work.  The numbered links will work, however.

I've included the jquery below because i believe it to be the source of the problem:

```
function pager(dir) {
    var page = parseInt($("#offset").val());
    var max = parseInt($("#maxpage").val());
    var no = isNaN(parseInt(dir));

    if (!no) {
        page = parseInt(dir);
    }

    if (dir == "next") page = page + 1;
    else if (dir == "first") page = 0;
    else page = page - 1;

    if (page == 0) {
        $("#prev").remove();
    } else $("#prev").add();

    if (page == max - 1) {
        $("#next").remove();
    } else $("#next").add();

    $.post("page.php", {
        val: page
    }, function (result) {
        $("#table-div").html(result);
    });
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: it will be nice if you can indent your code

Comment: sure. should have done that to begin with. did that help any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `var page = parseInt($("#offset").val());` line in your `pager` function. There is no element with an `id` attribute of `offset`. The result of `parseInt` is `NaN` and when you try to add a number to it, it doesn't add since `NaN` isn't a number.

You most likely forgot to add the element that contains the offset in your form somewhere. It looks like that's covered in **Step 9** of your tutorial.

Comment: another thing, you don't seem to be returning proper HTML. Some of your `<tr>` elements have apostrophes in them.

Comment: fixed the table problem, JohnP.  Francois, i do have that last echo statement in step nine.  One observation i made is that that echo statement isnt going to be made until after [ $.post("page.php",{val:page},function(result)  ] executes.  Also, could [ $offset = $_POST['val']; ] be a problem?  I dont know where val comes from.

Comment: @scifirocket - The problem that I see is that "page.php" doesn't include an element with an id attribute of "offset". That offset should be returned by page.php. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you aren't talking about those hidden inputs, then I guess I don't understand.

Comment: @scifirocket - I am talking about the hidden inputs. The first time you click on `Next` or `Previous`, the offset input doesn't exist. Create one with a value of 0 so that you jQuery call doesn't fail or display the first few results right away.

Comment: ok. next and previous work by manually creating those hidden input to start, but how am I going to get the table to show up initially?

Comment: @scifirocket - You should try calling `pager(1)` on load (i.e. body onload).

Answer (score 1):

Is there `createTable($link,$sql_offset,$limit);` in your php code, **Step 8**

Comment: Yes.  As the tutorial states, it is in my page.php.